# Pluggable conventions in a database first environment

Tags: entity-framework

Working with entity framework 6+ we now have access to add custom Conventions to the model builder like this.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(FilterConvention.Create<ITenantOwned, Guid>("TenantOwned", (e, tenantKey) => e.TenantKey == tenantKey));
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(FilterConvention.Create<ISoftDelete>("SoftDeleted", e => e.Deleted == false));
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

However I am unable to get this to work because all of our projects have an EDMX file. When you allow your metadata to be read in through the goofy connection string OnModelCreating never gets called. I am fine with OnModelCreating never getting called except that so far as I can tell I am unable to access the modelBuilder at any other time in order to inject my own Conventions into the model.

So is is it actually the case that Conventions are unavailable to non code first users, or am I overlooking something.